# Using endfloat package generates table heading in subsequent chapters

Tags: endfloat

I'm using endfloat package to put tables and figures at the end of each chapter. However, I find that there is a "table" heading even after the chapter ends. Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass [11pt, proquest] {uwthesis}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage[nomarkers, figuresfirst, nofiglist, notablist]{endfloat}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
\textpages

% ========== Chapter 1
\chapter {Introduction}
some text

\startlist{lot}

\section{chapter 1}
Some text

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Table 1 here \label{tab1}}
table 1 here
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Table 2 here \label{tab2}}
table 2 here
\end{table}

\processdelayedfloats

% ========== Chapter 2
\chapter{chapter 2}

\startlist{lot}
Some text
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Table 3 here \label{tab3}}
table 1 here
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Table 4 here \label{tab4}}
table 4 here
\end{table}

\processdelayedfloats

\end{document}
```

Another problem which is not shown here is that, even if I tried to put figures before tables by using [figuresfirst] option in endfloat, it always mixes tables and figures at the end.
Any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Nice first question - code compiles great! I suggest asking another question for the second problem, being sure to include an example which *does* reproduce the problem. You can link back to this question for context, if relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you can avoid it, start from a standard class rather than an off-the-peg thesis class. The latter seems easier to begin with, but typically ends up being more difficult to work with in the end. The exception to this is if the class is designed specifically for the format you need to use and you neither need nor wish (or wish but are not permitted) to make any changes to the format it provides.

If, however, you are near the submission deadline and your document is almost in the format you need, then you might consider the following, although it may have side-effects. To check this, carefully examine any page following the output of delayed floats trigged by use of `\processdelayedfloats`.

This uses `etoolbox` to patch `\processdelayedfloats` by appending `\clearpage\markdboth{}{}` to every occurrence.

[image: adjust page style following float pages]

```
\documentclass [11pt, proquest] {uwthesis}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage[nomarkers, figuresfirst, nofiglist, notablist]{endfloat}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd\processdelayedfloats{\clearpage\markboth{}{}}{\typeout{Hurray! Patched processdelayedfloats.}}{\typeout{Oh no! processdelayedfloats unpatched!}}
\begin{document}
\textpages

% ========== Chapter 1
\chapter {Introduction}
some text

\startlist{lot}

\section{chapter 1}
Some text

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Table 1 here \label{tab1}}
table 1 here
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Table 2 here \label{tab2}}
table 2 here
\end{table}

\processdelayedfloats

% ========== Chapter 2
\chapter{chapter 2}

\startlist{lot}
Some text
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Table 3 here \label{tab3}}
table 1 here
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Table 4 here \label{tab4}}
table 4 here
\end{table}

\processdelayedfloats

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works like a charm!! Thank you so much for providing the solution so promptly!